# Vuetify data table in single-select mode, selecting one row selects all others

Tags: vue.js, select, datatable, vuetify.js

I am trying to select one row in the table and emit the selected item.

Selecting one selects all but only the first encountered object is saved to the model (as `selected` variable).

Do you have any ideas, what i'm doing wrong?

[image]

```js
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :search="search"
    :loading="loading"
    v-model="selected"
    single-select
    show-select
    :options="{itemsPerPage:5}"
    @item-selected="itemSelected"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="mdi-magnify"
          label="Search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">{{ item.name }}</template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "variable-selector",
  props: ["variables", "map", "index"],
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      selected: {},
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      headers: [{ text: "Variable name", value: "name", sortable: true }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    itemSelected(selection) {
      if (selection.value) {
        this.$emit("selected", selection.item); // it always emits var_2 object
      } else {
        this.$emit("selected", null);
      }
    },

    updateItemsList(variables) {
      this.items = Array.from(variables);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.updateItemsList(this.variables);
  },

  watch: {
    variables(newValue) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.updateItemsList(newValue);
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Please create an answer instead of editing the solution announcement into the question. Or just accept the best one by using the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each object should be unique  key value if u face error , you want manually tell each object is unique

just add

```
item-key="table_header_index"//or name
```

eg:

```
<v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    show-select
    item-key="table_header_index"  <-------------------add this line
>

</v-data-table>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and the realized my `item-key="value"` did not match any of the values in my header. Select one of your header values and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

From the example in the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) I can see the following:

**1.) `selected` should be an array, not an object**

Selected holds all selected values. `single-select` property just determines if the length can be bigger than 1.

**2.) if you use `v-model` you should not use `@item-selected="itemSelected"`**

`v-model` is already 2 way binding. but you trigger an additional event and override the model (which should be an array) with an `object` or `null`

**Solution**

Make `selected` an array and remove `@item-selected="itemSelected"`.

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :search="search"
    :loading="loading"
    v-model="selected"
    single-select
    show-select
    :options="{itemsPerPage:5}"
  >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="search"
          append-icon="mdi-magnify"
          label="Search"
          single-line
          hide-details
        ></v-text-field>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>

    <template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">{{ item.name }}</template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "variable-selector",
  props: ["variables", "map", "index"],
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      selected: [],
      loading: false,
      items: [],
      headers: [{ text: "Variable name", value: "name", sortable: true }]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    updateItemsList(variables) {
      this.items = Array.from(variables);
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    this.updateItemsList(this.variables);
  },

  watch: {
    variables(newValue) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.updateItemsList(newValue);
      this.loading = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I forgot about this thread ... The solution to the problem is to add the parameters `selectable-key =" name "` and `item-key =" name "` to `v-data-table` and default to` "id" `. My items do not have such a field and it was necessary to indicate what the check was about.

Answer (score 0):

your data from back should have primary key. if it does it your table understand it; and if your data doesn't have primary key should write item-key for table.

good luck

Answer (score 0):

Quick update in November 2023, I had exactly this issue with a Vue3/vuetify app and the above solutions didn't solve it. I needed to use `item-value="my-key"` rather than `item-key`.

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="things" :search="search"
            show-select item-value="SortKey" v-model="selected"
            :footer-props="{ 'items-per-page-options': [10, 25, 50, 100] }"
            :sort-by="['Name']">
```

and then in the setup script, I was creating:

```
headers: [
        { title: 'Some Field', value: 'SortKey' }
      ]
```